# patient table database design

Tags: oracle, database-design, rdbms

I have two tables Patient and Doctor:

```
CREATE TABLE  "PATIENT" (   
    "PATIENT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PATIENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(40),
    "AGE" NUMBER,
    "SEX" VARCHAR2(12),
    "PLACE" VARCHAR2(40),
    "PHONE_NUMBER" NUMBER,
    "DOCTOR_ID" NUMBER,
    "REGISTRATION_DATE" DATE,
    CONSTRAINT "PATIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PATIENT_ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "DOCTOR_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("DOCTOR_ID")
    REFERENCES  "DOCTOR" ("DOCTOR_ID") ENABLE
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE  "DOCTOR" (    
    "DOCTOR_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DOCTOR_NAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PLACE" VARCHAR2(40),
    "PHONE_NUMBER" NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "DOCTOR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DOCTOR_ID") ENABLE
)
```

A patient can visit a doctor several times (different doctors also), so I have to insert the values on one key. Here `PATIENT_ID` is primary key so it can't accept multiple values on that key.

How can I recognize a record uniquely which tells about all the doctor visits of the patient? How would I create a patient table that suit my requirements?

Comment: if patient is visiting different doctors in different visits, would her id change?

Answer (score 2):

Create an additional table for recording the visits:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_VISITS (
DOCTOR_ID int references DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID)
PATIENT_ID int references PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
VISIT_DATE DATE,
)
```

This will allow you to track any patient visiting any doctor and record the date of the visit.

Comment: how can i manage the date attribute,may be every visit the date  will change

Comment: I've added a visit_date field to the table above.

Comment: now is it necessary that the patient table have the doctor_id as foreign key

Comment: IF you require that the patient has a specific doctor but it is possible for them to visit any doctor then you can leave it in. If you don't need to link them specifically then remove the DOCTOR_ID fk.

Comment: i taken visit_date as TIMESTAMP .How can i store current date and time as timestamp

Answer (score 1):

If a doctor can visit a patient more than once create a additional table like

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_VISITS (
DOCTOR_ID int references DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID)
PATIENT_ID int references PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
VISIT_DATE date
CONSTRAINT visit_pk PRIMARY KEY (DOCTOR_ID,PATIENT_ID,VISIT_DATE )
)
```

This would allow 1 visit per day. If you need more, I'd add time to that date field.

Comment: now is it necessary that the patient table have the doctor_id as foreign key

Comment: @techLearner: Not any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to build on Tommo1977's answer.
I definitely agree that an intersection table is the right approach.
However, remember that a compound primary key, such as [DOCTOR_ID, PATIENT_ID, VISIT_DATE (with or without a time component] is often replicated through many other tables (as a foreign key).
Therefore, I propose the following:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_VISITS (
VISIT_ID int
DOCTOR_ID int references DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID)
PATIENT_ID int references PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
VISIT_DATE date
CONSTRAINT visit_pk PRIMARY KEY (VISIT_ID )
)
```